# Ajax picture upload fails only on iOS: Internal Server Error

Tags: jquery, ios, ajax

I implemented an ajax file upload like described in http://abandon.ie/notebook/simple-file-uploads-using-jquery-ajax. Everything works fine in all browsers, but Safari on iOS. As response I get an Internal Server Error.

I checked my serverside code, but there's nothing wrong. I even get the error, if I write a `die();` at the first line of code in the serverside PHP script. It seems as if Safari uploads the picture wrongly. Maybe somebody can help me fix this bug. Thanks in advance!

This is the HTML-Code:

```
<input type="file" id="pict" accept="image/*">
<input type="text" id="field1">
<input type="text" id="field2">
<button id="send">Send</button>
```

And this the Javascript:

```
var files = false;

$('#pic').on('change', prepareUpload);

function prepareUpload(event)
{
    files = event.target.files;
}

$("body").on("click", "#send", function() {
        uploadTB();
});

function uploadTB() {
    var postdata = new FormData();
    if (files !== false){
    $.each(files, function(key, value)
    {
        postdata.append(key, value);
    });
    }
    postdata.append("field1", $("#field1").val());
    postdata.append("field2", $("#field2").val());
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://example.org/index.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data: postdata,
        cache: false,
        processData: false, 
        contentType: false, 
        success: function(data)
        {
           console.log("sucess");
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
        {
            console.log(jqXHR,textStatus,errorThrown);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to be a major bug in iOS 8. See: https://github.com/Widen/fine-uploader/issues/1284 
I could now borrow an iPad with iOS 7 and voila, it works. Thanks for all help!

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED CODE**

```
var files = false;

$('#pic').on('change', prepareUpload);

function prepareUpload(event)
{
    files = event.target.files;
}

$("body").on("click", "#send", function() {
        uploadTB();
});

function uploadTB() {
    var postdata = new FormData();
    if (files !== false){
    $.each(files, function(key, value)
    {
        postdata.append(key, value);
    });
    }
    postdata.append("field1", $("#field1").val());
    postdata.append("field2", $("#field2").val());
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://example.org/index.php',
        type: 'POST',
        data:  formData,
        mimeType:"multipart/form-data",
        contentType: false,
        cache: false,
        processData:false,
        success: function(data)
        {
           console.log("sucess");
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
        {
            console.log(jqXHR,textStatus,errorThrown);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Sadly this does not solve it. To see if it uploads I added an XHR Progress Listener, which stays at 0%, with or without mimetype attribute.

Comment: @dboth Try putting all your element in a form. Hope this will work.